# ReferenceError: next is not defined In Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I am getting an error on calling `next(error)` in the patch function:

`(node:1004) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: next is not defined.`

```js
const express = require("express");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const Url = require("../models/Url");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const HttpError = require("../models/http-errors");

const getTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  let url;
  try {
    url = await Url.find({});
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Something went wrong, could not find a Url.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  if (!url) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Could not find a place for the provided id.",
      404
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  res.json({
    url: url.map((url) => url.toObject({ getters: true })),
  });
};

const addTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { content } = req.body;
  const createdPlace = new Url({
    content: content,
    enable: false,
  });
  // Sending it To Mongo
  try {
    await createdPlace.save();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError("Creating Place fails mongo");
    return next(error);
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
};

const deleteTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { urlId } = req.body;

  let url;
  try {
    url = await Url.findById(urlId);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Something went wrong, could not delete place.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  if (!url) {
    const error = new HttpError("Could not find Url for this id.", 404);
    return next(error);
  }

  //sending it to Mongo
  try {
    const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
    sess.startTransaction();
    await url.remove({ session: sess });
    await sess.commitTransaction();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Something went wrong, could not delete place.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Deleted place." });
};

const patchTodo = async (req, res, nect) => {
  const { urlId, enable } = req.body;

  let url;
  try {
    url = await Url.findById(urlId);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Something went wrong, could not Update place.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  url.enable = enable;
  //sending it to Mongo
  try {
    await url.save();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Something went wrong, could not Update place.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  res.status(200).json({ url: url.toObject({ getters: true }) });
};

exports.getTodo = getTodo;
exports.addTodo = addTodo;
exports.deleteTodo = deleteTodo;
exports.patchTodo = patchTodo;
```

Here it's the HttpError that I created.

```js
class HttpError extends Error {
  constructor(message, errorCode) {
    super(message); // Add a "message" property
    this.code = errorCode; // Adds a "code" property
  }
}

module.exports = HttpError;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see clearly, you have spelled `nect` and you are using **next**, which is not defined clearly.

```
const patchTodo = async (req, res, nect) => {
                                    ^^^
```

Comment: wow thanks when you work on too much time on a project you don't see the big picture.